# any way to deform normals?

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view, normals, 3d-cursor

These meshes need to be scaled up *or moved* along their normals.

<kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> works pretty well but they, obviously, go straight on their directions...

Any way to deform these normals to follow a circular path around the current 3D-cursor? *or origin as well..*

[image]

---

update:
I solved this way:

- pivot to 3D-cursor
- trasformation orientation to normal
- extruded meshes
- rotated meshes

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand this correctly This could be easier to achieve with the help of some modifiers.
If you model a single cog and use a mirror modifier to make it's symmetry it will simplify the process so that you only have to rotate two edges in one direction. Followe that by adding an array modifier to accomplish the whole gear it will take care of the rest.

[image]

Comment: It was not what I meant.. but It let me to a similar solution! added an update to the question! Your solution is surely a better way of creating gears! I started from extra objects: gear add-on :)